# How to plot multiple top-bottom lines using gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need a little help with a program I am writing for my scientific research. We have a lot of data, and I have to create a program in Java that reads all that, make some calculus, and plot the result.
What I want is to plot something like this (that was made using Excel):

[image: Using Excel]

The input data looks like something like this:

```
Profundidade (mm);Circular (%);Intermediário (%);Alongado (%)
27.78;0;0;0
26.1;0;0;0
25.26;0.0134911243;0;0
24.42;0;0;0
23.58;0;0;0
22.74;0;0;0
21.06;0;0;0
20.22;0.0357396450;0;0
19.38;0;0;0
18.54;0;0;0
17.70;0;0;0
16.86;0;0;0
```

Using the code below, we got the following result:

```
set datafile separator ";"
set term png size 800,600 font "Times New Roman, 10"
set output 'test.png'
set pointsize 2
set y2range[0:40]
set xlabel 'MAP (%)'
set ylabel 'Profundidade (mm)'
set tics scale 0.0
set grid y
set x2tics
startcol = 2
endcol = 4
plot for [col=startcol:endcol] 'test.csv' u col:x2tic(1) w linespoints title columnheader(col)
```

[image: Result so far]

Do you have any ideas to solve this, what steps should I take?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite certain I understand exactly what you want.

The gnuplot code looks like you want to have the values of column 1 as axis labels (tics). The excell example looks like a scatterplot with a fitted function. The first part, scatterplot, is easy to explain. For the fit more information is needed, most of all, what type of fit would you like? Splines?

A very simple xy plot:

```
plot "test.csv" using ($2):($1), "" u ($3):($1), "" u ($4):($1)
```

The `using` specifies the columns used for x:y. The commas seperate sets of points; `using` is shortened to `u`. There is still the first line, that is in the way, the easiest would be to comment it out with # in the dat file, then you can name the points.

```
plot "test.csv" u ($2):($1) with points title "Circular"\
, "" u ($3):($1) w p  t "Intermediário"\
, "" u ($4):($1) w p  t "Alongado"
```

The `\` allows to write in multiple lines, make sure that the line ends after it, no space, comments or other characters. The `,` moved to the next line, and delimits sets of data as before. `with points` or `w p` sets the data to show as points. `title` or `t` sets a title to show up in the key. This one can be moved with a different command `set key`, e.g. `set key bottom right`.

If you don't want to comment out the first line in your data file, you can use the `every ::1` parameter directly after `using`, and look into getting title from a data line.

In the example I used points and not lines or linespoints, since that would simply connect the datapoints with lines. In your example you want a more complex curve. Look up what you want by searching the web for "fitting gnuplot".

Comment: Thanks! I am sure that will help. I'll try that as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure where to post the result I got with your help, but the final script was this:
    set style data points
    set pointsize 1
    set yrange[35:0]
    set x2label 'MAP (%)'
    set x2tics
    plot for [col=startcol:endcol] 'test.csv' u col:1 w linespoints lt col pt col title columnheader(col)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm happy I could help.